# Delete few duplicate rows from table in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got a list of around 5 users which have duplicate entries in the table.
Here is the query i used to get the duplicate entries. Please suggest some easy way to delete few entries.

```
USE [DB]

SELECT UserName, COUNT(*) AS CountOF 
FROM UserDetails
WHERE RoleID = '2'
GROUP BY UserName
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using MySQL (and not SQL Server)?  What is the structure of the table?

Comment: I am using sql server. Sorry about the wrong tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The use of square braces suggests SQL Server.  If so, you can do:

```
WITH todelete as (
      SELECT ud.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY RoleId, username ORDER BY RoleId) as seqnum
      FROM UserDetails
      WHERE RoleID = 2
     )
DELETE FROM todelete
    WHERE seqnum > 1;
```

Note:  If `RoleId` is a number, then don't compare the value to a string.

Comment: yes role id is a number. If there are 2 duplicate entries , the above query will delete one right ?

Comment: This logic will keep one value for each `username` for `RoleId = 2`.

Answer (score 0):

need another uniq column like id or createtime 
more database support

```
with repeatData as (
    SELECT UserName,COUNT(*) as CountOF,min(id) as keepTag FROM UserDetails
    WHERE RoleID = '2'
    GROUP BY UserName
    HAVING COUNT(*)>1),
toDelData as (
    select id from UserDetails 
    where UserName in (SELECT UserName from repeatData) 
    and id not in (SELECT keepTag from repeatData) )
delete FROM UserDetails where id in (select id from toDelData )
```